# Items move around when window size change

Tags: html, css

To learn how to make different types of websites, and sometimes just for fun, I find cool websites and challenge myself to make them. I'm still quite new to web design however, and have stumbled across an error. I remember fixing it a while back but cannot remember how. If I re-size the page, the header items move about the screen and end up falling beneath each other.

CSS:

```
max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        margin:0;
        background-image: url("images\bg.png");
        background-width:100%;
    }

    #topbar{
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 122px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .logo{
        position:absolute; z-index: 100;
        padding-left:245px;
        padding-top:40px
    }

    #topmenu{
        position:absolute; z-index: 100;
        font-family: ‘Arial Narrow’, sans-serif;
        margin-left:67%;
        padding-top:15px;
    }

    #bigmenu{
        position:absolute; z-index: 100;
        font-family: 'Arial Narrow', sans-serf;
        margin-left:49%;
        margin-top:80px;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .big-link{
        text-decoration:none;
        padding-right:12px;
        padding-left:12px;
        padding-top:25px;
        padding-bottom:25px;
        color: #00CBFF;
        font-size:16px;
    }

    .big-link:hover{
        background-color:black;
        color:#91E5FA;
    }

    .clickable-link{
        text-decoration:none;
        margin:6px;
        color:#91E5FA;
        font-size:13px;
    }

    .clickable-link:hover{
        color:#00AAD2;
    }

    .headerback{
        position:absolute;rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) z-index: 1000;
        margin-right:300px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="container">

<div id="top">

    <div class="logo">

    <a href="index.html"><img src="images\logo.png" /></a>

    </div>

        <div class="headerback">

            <img src="images\headerback.png" />

        </div>

        <div id="topmenu">
                <a href="#" class="clickable-link"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
                <a href="#" class="clickable-link"><strong>F.A.Q.</strong></a>
                <a href="#" class="clickable-link"><strong>Client Login</strong></a>
                <a href="#" class="clickable-link"><strong>Register</strong></a>
        </div>

        <div id="bigmenu">
                <a href="#" class="big-link"><strong>HOME</strong></a>
                <a href="#" class="big-link"><strong>MINECRAFT</strong></a>
                <a href="#" class="big-link"><strong>DOMAINS</strong></a>
                <a href="#" class="big-link"><strong>WEB HOSTING</strong></a>
                <a href="#" class="big-link"><strong>VIRTUAL SERVERS</strong></a>
        </div>

    <div id="topbar">

    </div>



</div>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Sorry if I come across as a noob. By the way, the original site is https://www.ownagehosting.com/ (I just thought they had a really cool website and the javascript/jquery looked like fun work).

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify different max-width values for different screen, in that way you take control of your the sizes of the elements inside divisions

```
@media (max-width: 990px){
     /*set your element sizes for device that size*/
}

@media (max-width: 770px){
     /*set your element sizes for device that size*/
}

@media (max-width: 450px){
     /*set your element sizes for device that size*/
}
```

this is just an example, you can specify the relevant screen sizes you want.

Comment: For that do you mean that I need to add a max-width property to each element on my screen?  Could you use a direct example from my code to help me better understand?

Comment: essentially, yes you will have to put under each media max width specify divisions you want resized and their orientation